# How to automatically git pull and rebuild app on remote server when required?

Tags: bash, jenkins

When i want to update my app running on server, i should `ssh` to server, cd to app folder, execute git pull, then i should run npm build, next i should restart the server. How to automate this with bash script or something? Is it the case for which `jenkins` stands for (or some other tools)?.

But how to do this with simple bash script or something?

I dont need the rebuilding of an app every time i push to git, only when i need to update and restart everything.

Also it there a way if build take a lot of time notify me by email that build success?

For now eery time i do update for remote app, i should wait with open terminal when it builded and only then i can close the sshed terminal. Some time builds take a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply script those commands, and put that script on your server.
That way, all you need to do is to ssh to that server and call that script, which will execute those commands on demand.

> Is it the case for which jenkins stands for (or some other tools)?

Not in this case, since it is purely on demand: you can execute the script through a simple ssh call, no need for Jenkins.

Comment: but when people use jenkins? i thinked jenkins about this

Comment: @TylerBrin You actually can use Jenkins for this, but it is more for *scheduling* a task (after a commit, or every n minutes, or ...). Still, if you just want to call that script on demand (whenever you want) through a Jenkins job, you can.